# Bring previously added view to front

Tags: ios, uiview, subview, addsubview

My problem is the following:

I have a view and to that view I add 3 subViews(`view1`,`view2`,`view3`) in that order. The views slightly overlap. I want to bring the first view to the top but I just can't get it to work.

I tried adding the views with `insertSubview:atIndex:` and giving `view1` a larger index and I tried using `addSubview:` and then bringSubviewToTop but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

P.S. I can't add the views in a different order. They have to be added in this order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bringSubviewToFront should work, just make sure you're using it correctly. The usage is.

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:view1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the method `bringSubviewToFront:`

Moves the specified subview so that it appears on top of its siblings.

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view
```

Parameters

- *view*: The subview to move to the front.