# How to show the tool bar in map view?

Tags: ios, xcode5, mkmapview

I add toolbar in my story board in the below of navigation and map view and link it but it show only the navigation bar … at the output please give me the solution for that i tried so many but it won't…coming..please help me….

Comment: You might have a Z-order issue, where the toolbar is below the mapview.  Fix in IB or via code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097952/bring-previously-added-view-to-front).  Prove this by marking your mapview as not visible

Comment: i use only one view but it not display….i placed the tool bar in between the navigation bar and map view..